# Change default.htm for bot homepage?

Tags: .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service

I noticed that the bot is basically a web server and it does have a /wwwroot/default.htm file. We also want to make a web client for our bot. Instead of creating an html file and hosting it somewhere, can't I just replace the default.htm code that the bot comes with by default with our own code?

I tried this but I noticed that my changes don't reflect when I debug my bot. I change the code for default.htm hoping to make it a web ui for the bot ([like in this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use)), but the home page is always the same no matter how much I change my html. I even deleted the file but there is still a homepage for the bot (when I go to http://localhost:3978/ in my browser).

Comment: Unless your web server or browser is caching the file, I don't see how this is possible... Have you tried to restart the web server and clear the cache

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks you're right. It was just my browser's cache.

Comment: @sidecus if you want to post that as an answer, I can mark it as the official answer.

Comment: ok. moving an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your web server or browser is caching the file, I don't see how this is possible... Have you tried to restart the web server and clear the cache?